# how to handle list item widget from outside Adapter

Tags: android, listview, button

I had a requirement where I need to implement a ListAdapter which should be used for only display purpose. 
 Each list item row contains a button. 
 I have written an Adapter subclass which extends BaseAdapater separately as a file not with in activity. 
 My query is  I need to catch the Button click on listitem  of list from activity. 
In otherwords I need to handle widget click on a list item  from outside Adapter class.

My code will be like below:

## MyAdapter.java

public MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{ 
 }

## MyActivity.java

public class MyActivity extends Activity { 
ListView lv  = (findViewById) R.id.list;  
lv.setAdapter(new MyAdpater());

//Here I need to capture widget click on list item 
Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue ? 
 Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you need to catch it outside then try to set listener outside. Should look like lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClick...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass a custom interface t from the activity to the adapter, and to invoke it when 
each button is being clicked in getView method.
Something like this:

```
   public MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    { 
        private OnListItemClick onClickListener;

        public void setOnItemClickListener(OnListItemClick onClickListener)
        {
          this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
        }

        View getView(.....)
        {
            button  = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
              {
                 onClick(View view)
                 {
                    onClickListener.onListItemClick(position);
                 }

              }
             )

        } 

        public interface OnListItemClick{
          public void onListItemClick(int position);
         }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend BaseAdapter with your custom and add abstract method for invoke when button was clicked, here how it's gonna look like:

```
public abstract CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 

   //custom constructors and other staff

    public View getView(int position, ...) {

        //custom view initialization

        Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                buttonClickEvent(position);
             }
        });
    }

    public abstract void buttonClickEvent(int position);
}
```

Later in your code before setting adapter, create instance of CustomAdapter where you could implement everything you want.
Cheers!

Comment: how to get the position of clicked list item  from activity ?

Comment: There are few parameters there getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent). You just need to pass position to buttonClickEvent. I'll edit my answer for you.

Comment: Yes , I got it . I  tried with setting listener outside .Thanks a lot